# Creating an object without knowing the class name at design time

Tags: c#, reflection

Using reflection, I need to investigate a user DLL and create an object of a class in it.

What is the simple way of doing it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

`System.Reflection.Assembly` is the class you will want to use. It contains many method for iterating over the types contained with a user DLL. You can iterate through each class, perhaps see if it inherits from a particular interface etc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly_members.aspx

Investigate `Assembly.GetTypes()` method for getting the list of types, or `Assembly.GetExportedTypes()` for the public ones only.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an instance of a class from a Type object using Activator.CreateInstance, to get all types in a dll you can use Assembly.GetTypes

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these links:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Development-Class/Createanobjectusingreflection.htm

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3a58006.aspx

You basically use reflection to load an assembly, then find a type you're interested in. Once you have the type, you can ask to find it's constructors or other methods / properties. Once you have the constructor, you can invoke it. Easy!

Answer (score 1):

As it has already been said, you need to poke the System.Reflection namespace.

If you know in advance the location/name of the DLL you want to load, you need to iterate through the Assembly.GetTypes().

In Pseudocode it would look something like this:

Create and assembly object.

Iterate through all the types contained in the assembly.

Once you find the one you are looking for, invoke it (CreateInstance)…

Use it wisely.

;)

I have plenty of Reflection code if you want to take a look around, but the task is really simple and there are at least a dozen of articles with samples out there in the wild. (Aka Google). 
Despite that, the MSDN is your friend for Reflection Reference.