# Purpose of Activator.CreateInstance with example?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Can someone explain `Activator.CreateInstance()` purpose in detail?

Comment: Probably that the greater documentation and example isn't available in the generic overloads. I would encourage that the documentation from `CreateInstance(Type type)` is matched with the `CreateInstance<T>()` overload.

Comment: The MSDN page just has a single explanatory line, "Contains methods to create types of objects locally or remotely, or obtain references to existing remote objects. This class cannot be inherited." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.aspx

Comment: If you've come here from a Java background, this is the `c#.net` way of doing [`Object xyz = Class.forName(className).newInstance();`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268817/create-new-class-from-a-variable-in-java).

Comment: There's better documentation for it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator?view=netframework-4.8#remarks).

Comment: @SNag I only need newInstance() in Java for classes where I'm not allowed to add a constructor with parameters and I can't set member values later. I haven't had a use case other than Adroid fragments yet. This means I won't use CreateInstance() until I'm forced to do. :)

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Say you have a class called `MyFancyObject` like this one below:

```
class MyFancyObject
{
 public int A { get;set;}
}
```

It lets you turn:

```
String ClassName = "MyFancyObject";
```

Into

```
MyFancyObject obj;
```

Using

```
obj = (MyFancyObject)Activator.CreateInstance("MyAssembly", ClassName))
```

and can then do stuff like:

```
obj.A = 100;
```

That's its purpose. It also has many other overloads such as providing a `Type` instead of the class name in a string. Why you would have a problem like that is a different story. Here's some people who needed it:

- [Createinstance() - Am I doing this right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742321/createinstance-am-i-doing-this-right)
- [C# Using Activator.CreateInstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262693/c-using-activator-createinstance)
- [Creating an object without knowing the class name at design time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649/creating-an-object-without-knowing-the-class-name-at-design-time)

Comment: This proved useful to me. In my case, the class was in a different namespace, so I had to make sure that I included the namespace in my ClassName string (i.e. `String ClassName = "My.Namespace.MyFancyObject";`).

Comment: You forgot to add the Unwrap(). You can also put null, instead of "MyAssembly", and system will search current Assembly.

Comment: Can I do something like this `obj = (MyFancyObject)Activator.CreateInstance("MyAssembly", ClassName))` but instead of casting with the type. Cast with type made from the ClassName? Like this `Type type = Type.GetType(ClassName);obj = (type )Activator.CreateInstance("MyAssembly", ClassName))` ?

Comment: @Pan.student **YES** for more info, here is a perfect tutorial video showcasing that exact line of code, using generics and delegates. [JeremyBytes - C# Generics - Part 3: Methods & Delegates - You Tube](https://youtu.be/PrQumlfBZVw?t=282)

Comment: If I simply use MyFancyObject obj = new MyFancyObject() I can do the same with much lesser code.

Comment: @TheincredibleJan The example here is for cases where you cannot know at design time the type. If you know at design time the type it will be, then you are correct.

Answer (score 64):

Well i can give you an example why to use something like that. Think of a game where you want to store your level and enemies in an XML file. When you parse this file, you might have an element like this.

```
<Enemy X="10" Y="100" Type="MyGame.OrcGuard"/>
```

what you can do now is, create dynamically the objects found in your level file.

```
foreach(XmlNode node in doc)
   var enemy = Activator.CreateInstance(null, node.Attributes["Type"]);
```

This is very useful, for building dynamic enviroments. Of course its also possible to use this for Plugin or addin scenarios and alot more.

Comment: I understood that it was to create a new instance of a type, but this is a nice simple example of why one would want to do so.

Comment: Are you saying that the benefit is that using dynamic environments allows for polymorphic-like (polymorphism-like) programming?

Comment: Your code sets the local variable "enemy" to whatever the current node is and after the loop is done you have nothing?

Comment: Well, it is an pseudo-code example, not meant as a full a-z program. So whatever you do with enemy is up to you and not important for the example.

Answer (score 16):

My good friend MSDN [can explain it to you, with an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx)

Here is the code in case the link or content changes in the future:

```
using System;

class DynamicInstanceList
{
    private static string instanceSpec = "System.EventArgs;System.Random;" +
        "System.Exception;System.Object;System.Version";

    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] instances = instanceSpec.Split(';');
        Array instlist = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), instances.Length);
        object item;
        for (int i = 0; i < instances.Length; i++)
        {
            // create the object from the specification string
            Console.WriteLine("Creating instance of: {0}", instances[i]);
            item = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(instances[i]));
            instlist.SetValue(item, i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nObjects and their default values:\n");
        foreach (object o in instlist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type:     {0}\nValue:    {1}\nHashCode: {2}\n",
                o.GetType().FullName, o.ToString(), o.GetHashCode());
        }
    }
}

// This program will display output similar to the following: 
// 
// Creating instance of: System.EventArgs 
// Creating instance of: System.Random 
// Creating instance of: System.Exception 
// Creating instance of: System.Object 
// Creating instance of: System.Version 
// 
// Objects and their default values: 
// 
// Type:     System.EventArgs 
// Value:    System.EventArgs 
// HashCode: 46104728 
// 
// Type:     System.Random 
// Value:    System.Random 
// HashCode: 12289376 
// 
// Type:     System.Exception 
// Value:    System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown. 
// HashCode: 55530882 
// 
// Type:     System.Object 
// Value:    System.Object 
// HashCode: 30015890 
// 
// Type:     System.Version 
// Value:    0.0 
// HashCode: 1048575
```

Comment: Unlikely to happen for MSDN, and copying the content here is *almost* a violation of copyright ;)

Comment: You're right. Personally I feel the principle also works to give better answers. I often come to SO with a lot on my mind from my current project. I usually just want a simple and to-the-point answer, so I can continue where I left off. I hate having to open up articles, which sometimes even link to other articles. Many answerers don't realize that many people don't come here with time on their hands to read through several articles, with a ton of unnecessary introductions and talks. Briefly summing up the important parts of a good article is key to some of the greatest answers I've seen.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen I have been told that Microsoft explicitly allows their content to be copied. However in general I agree that content should not be copied from elsewhere without permission but people in StackOverflow tend to downvote answers that link to somewhere else without something more than what has been provided here, excluding the code that was copied.

Answer (score 15):

You can also do this -

```
var handle = Activator.CreateInstance("AssemblyName", 
                "Full name of the class including the namespace and class name");
var obj = handle.Unwrap();
```

Comment: The Unwrap() was the missing piece. :)

Comment: I can't find the 'Unwrap()' method above to use (as above). Has something changed in the new .NET APIs?

Comment: It's still there in System namespace.

Comment: Could you provide some additional explanation on what `.Unwrap()` does precisely and how this relates to other solutions?

Comment: @Sam it's on a different overload of `CreateInstance` where it returns `System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle`.

Answer (score 10):

A good example could be next: for instance you have a set of Loggers and you allows user to specify type to be used in runtime via configuration file.

Then:

```
string rawLoggerType = configurationService.GetLoggerType();
Type loggerType = Type.GetType(rawLoggerType);
ILogger logger = Activator.CreateInstance(loggerType.GetType()) as ILogger;
```

OR another case is when you have a common entities factory, which creates entity, and is also responsible on initialization of an entity by data received from DB:

(pseudocode)

```
public TEntity CreateEntityFromDataRow<TEntity>(DataRow row)
 where TEntity : IDbEntity, class
{
   MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(T).GetMethod("BuildFromDataRow");
   TEntity instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TEntity)) as TEntity;
   return methodInfo.Invoke(instance, new object[] { row } ) as TEntity;
}
```

Comment: This does not work, `typeof(loggerType)` results in `loggerType is a variable and used like a type`

Answer (score 5):

The `Activator.CreateInstance` method creates an instance of a specified type using the constructor that best matches the specified parameters.

For example, let's say that you have the type name as a string, and you want to use the string to create an instance of that type. You could use `Activator.CreateInstance` for this:

```
string objTypeName = "Foo";
Foo foo = (Foo)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(objTypeName));
```

Here's an MSDN article that explains it's application in more detail:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx

Comment: Or you could just use `new Foo()`. I think the OP wanted a more realistic example.

Comment: I agree with @Konrad. The reason for using `CreateInstance` is if you don't know the type of object you are going to instantiate at design time. In this example, you clearly know it's of type `Foo` since you are casting it as type `Foo`. You would never do this because you can just do `Foo foo = new Foo()`.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of deepee1 and [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f5e5f3c8-ac3a-49c7-8dd2-e248c8736ffd/using-variable-table-name-in-linq-syntax?forum=linqprojectgeneral), here's how to accept a class name in a string, and then use it to read and write to a database with LINQ. I use "dynamic" instead of deepee1's casting because it allows me to assign properties, which allows us to dynamically select and operate on any table we want.

```
Type tableType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("NameSpace.TableName");
ITable itable = dbcontext.GetTable(tableType);

//prints contents of the table
foreach (object y in itable) {
    string value = (string)y.GetType().GetProperty("ColumnName").GetValue(y, null);
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}

//inserting into a table
dynamic tableClass = Activator.CreateInstance(tableType);
//Alternative to using tableType, using Tony's tips
dynamic tableClass = Activator.CreateInstance(null, "NameSpace.TableName").Unwrap();
tableClass.Word = userParameter;
itable.InsertOnSubmit(tableClass);
dbcontext.SubmitChanges();

//sql equivalent
dbcontext.ExecuteCommand("INSERT INTO [TableNme]([ColumnName]) VALUES ({0})", userParameter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Coupled with reflection, I found Activator.CreateInstance to be very helpful in mapping stored procedure result to a custom class as described in [the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47999079/2093880).

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use it if you already knew the class and were going to cast it?
Why not just do it the old fashioned way and make the class like you always make it? There's no advantage to this over the way it's done normally.
Is there a way to take the text and operate on it thusly:

```
label1.txt = "Pizza" 
Magic(label1.txt) p = new Magic(lablel1.txt)(arg1, arg2, arg3);
p.method1();
p.method2();
```

If I already know its a Pizza there's no advantage to:

```
p = (Pizza)somefancyjunk("Pizza"); over
Pizza p = new Pizza();
```

but I see a huge advantage to the Magic method if it exists.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68923409/7111561) answers your questions ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have an abstract class called GetTestQueryValidatorTest<TQuery, TValidator>. In this scenario, I am not aware of the exact object, so I have to use Activator.CreateInstance for unit testing.

```
    public abstract class GetTestQueryValidatorTest<TQuery, TValidator>
    where TQuery : CreateTestCommandValidator
    where TValidator : AbstractValidator<TQuery>
 {
    [Fact]
    public async Task CreateTestQueryValidator_Check_Value()
    {
        //Arrenge
        var sut = Activator.CreateInstance<TValidator>();

        object query;

        query = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TQuery),
        TestResultDataConstant.LESS_THAN_ZERO,
        TestResultDataConstant.UPPER_THAN_TEN
        )!;

        //Act
        var result = await sut.TestValidateAsync((TQuery)query!);

        //Assert
        result.Errors.Select(s => s.ErrorMessage).Should().Contain(nameof(ErrorMessage.Code_Minimum_Number_Is_1);
        result.Errors.Select(s => s.ErrorMessage).Should().Contain(nameof(ErrorMessage.Name_Minimum_Is_10));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?