# Stuck with "Cannot find type" error using CreateInstance()

Tags: c#, dll, assemblies, createinstance

I am trying to use `.CreateInstance()` in a connection utility in a C# project, while serializing XML. `.Unwrap()` is used to unwrap the serializable return type and get an instance of the type I'm trying to create.

```
String fileToLoad = @"D:\RPMOpen\svnCobra\conversion\aui\Model\bin\Debug\RPM_Model";
String file = Path.GetFileName(fileToLoad);
AbstractResponseMessageData response = 
    (AbstractResponseMessageData)Activator.CreateInstance(file, responseName).Unwrap();
```

My assembly `RPM_Model` at `@"D:\RPMOpen\svnCobra\conversion\aui\Model\bin\Debug\RPM_Model"` loads fine, but as a result of the type `ARC_LOGONRS` in `responseName` I get the following error:

> Error in method ConnectUtil.Execute:
>   Could not load type `ARC_LOGONRS` from assembly `RPM_Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`.

Now, this is why I am stuck on the error: 

**1.** I *did* reference the assembly specified in the error. 
**2.** There *is not* anything in my GAC overriding the .dll in my `/Debug` folder. 
**3.** I have ensured that I have the correct version of the .dll. 
**4.** The .dll has no other dependencies. 
**5.** Both my project and the .dll have the same target platform. 
**6.** I *know* that I am referencing the assembly properly, as if I place `ARCLOGON_RS` in my code and hover over it I see

> class RPM.Model.Data.ARCLOGON_RS

and I can `f12` focus on it to see it's properties. 
**7.** I have cleaned and rebuilt both solutions. 
**8.** The type *does* have a public default constructor, and the class is public. 
**9.** The .dll *is* in the reference node. 
**10.** I *do* have the right Assembly Name passed as a parameter.

**My question is** if anyone has any other idea as to why my project may be throwing this error, and how I may go about fixing it, as I have completely run out of diagnoses.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Does the type have a public default constructor?

Comment: @RufusL Yes, sorry, forgot that, edited question.

Comment: silly question but does the DLL exist in the same folder as the application you are running?

Comment: Is there an inner exception? According to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typeloadexception(v=vs.110).aspx, the reason may be DllNotFound, EntryPointNotFound, or TypeAccess exception. That should at least help narrow it down.

Comment: The inner exception just points me at the `AbstractResponseMessageData` line. From those three I would think it would have to be EntryPointNotFound but I have no idea how to diagnose the exception any further.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas and yes it does.

Comment: have you checked to make sure that the `Dll` is in the reference node..also check to see if `CopyLocal=true` is set.. || http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598088/purpose-of-activator-createinstance-with-example

Comment: You said the constructor is public, but is the class?

Comment: @MethodMan The .dll is in the reference node, I will take a look at your second suggestion.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway And yes the constructor is public, updated the question with that info.

Comment: What happens when you call the overload `Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("RPM.Model.Data.ARCLOGON_RS, RPM_Model", true))`?

Comment: @NightOwl888 Could not load type `RPM.Model.Data.ARCLOGON_RS` from assembly `RPM_Model`.

Comment: I asked if the _class_ was public, not the constructor.  But I see you have resolved your problem.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway My apologies I meant the class, I have absolutely no idea why I typed constructor.

Answer (score 1):

When supplying the typeName to `CreateInstance()` I had to hardcode the full type. Despite my error looking as though it is looking within `RPM.Model.Data` as I would like it to, it apparently wasn't. Editing `responseName` to be `RPM.Model.Data.ARC_LOGONRS` instead of simply `ARC_LOGONRS` was all that was necessary to overcome the error.