# Making an overriden method's super refer to the superclasss super

Tags: java, inheritance, bukkit

I know the title might sound a bit weird, but that's exactly what I'm willing to do. Simply explained:
`Class A` is a sub-class of `class B`, and `class B` is also a sub-class of `class C`.

Now, all those classes contain the method `m()`. In my `A` class, the only one I have access to, as the others are only available at runtime, I override the `B` class's `m()` method. 
However, the `m()` method of the `B` class contains a call to the `m()` method of it's own superclass (that is `C`), and, although I made some modifications to it, I eventually also have to call that method.

I have searched for a while and I've heard that in similar situations this would be impossible as it would "break encapsulation", and I really understand why. However, in my case, I'm doing it all inside an overriden method, so is there any way I can actually make it so it would work this way? Thanks!

EDIT:
Ahm, I think I didn't explain quiet well. I'm only overriding the method from the B class in my C class. From there, inside my method in the C class, I need to call the m() method not of the B class (which would work for super.m()) but for the C class.

Here's my actual code if it might help:

```
    @Override
public void m() {

    if(this.au() && this.getGoalTarget() != null && this.vehicle instanceof EntityChicken) {
        ((EntityInsentient) this.vehicle).getNavigation().a(this.getNavigation().j(), 1.5D);
    }

    try {
        ((EntityMonster) this.getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getConstructor(World.class).newInstance(this.world)).m();
    }catch(InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: You said your class B method already invokes super (C) method. What else do you want?

Comment: This all sounds a little confusing, so `A extends B` which extends `C` - fairly enough; and the method `m()` in class `B` has something like `super.m()` - which calls method `m()` of class `C` - I don't understand what you say the problem is here? Even if you override a method of the base class (`C.m()`), nothing stops you from calling that method using `super.m()` from the child (class `B`) in your case.

Comment: Ahm, I think I didn't explain quiet well. I'm only overriding the method from the B class in my C class. From there, inside my method in the C class, I need to call the m() method not of the B class (which would work for super.m()) but for the C class.

Comment: Your edit seems contradictory. You have a `C` base class, which is extended by `B`, and finally you have `A` that extends `B`. From general to particular, `C -> B -> A`. But then, in your edit, you say you are overriding method `m()` in `C`, which doesn't make sense since it's the base class. Please clarify.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner No, I'm saying that, from class C, I am overriding the m() method in class B.

Comment: So, your hierarchy is `A -> B -> C`, where `A` is the base class and `C` is the most particular one, and you only have access to `C`. Is this right?

Comment: why dont you try simple functional interface with default method thing , make two interfaces with each method and implement both  ,and use it by lambada , keep it simple

Comment: @holidayCoder I don't understand what uou mean lol. You should keep in mind I'm kinda new to Java, I have no idea what lambda is.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use inheritance, then you should give the [*decorator pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) a chance.

In the motivation section:

> ...sometimes (e.g., using external frameworks) it is not possible, legal, or convenient to modify the base class.

In your case, you could use the decorator pattern to add functionality to the `C` class (the class that inherits from `B`):

```
class A {
    public void m() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public void m() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}

class C extends B {

    private final A base;

    public C(A base) { // pass other needed arguments
        this.base = base;
    }

    public void m() {
        this.base.m(); // instead of super.m()
        System.out.println("C");
    }
}
```

You'd need to instantiate `C` as follows:

```
A base = new A();
C c = new C(base);
```

And then:

```
c.m();
```

Which should print:

```
A
C
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do that. Maybe I should have explained it better the first time... I'm using Bukkit, and what I'm actually trying to do is to create a custom entity which aims to replace the default one. While the class for the default one is still there, I tell Bukkit to just use my class instead of that one. Also, my class inherits all the behaviour of the default class, but it adds something to it. Anyways, the thing is, I'm not the one who instantiates my class, Bukkit is. And it can only instantiate it with the normal argument of the default Zombie class (world)...

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to call it this way?

```
public class C {

    public void m() throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        System.out.println("C");
    }
}

public class B extends C {
    @Override
    public void m() throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        super.m();
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}

public class A extends B {
    @Override
    public void m() throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        ((C) this.getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().newInstance()).m();
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, let me see, I'll check if it works right now, but yes, that's what I want to do in theory. Never tough of using reflection though.

Comment: Ahm, unfortunately, it doesn't work in my case. I get an Instantiationexception:
http://hastebin.com/secepakexo.avrasm

Comment: Do you support a default constructor?

Comment: Otherwise you maybe need to use an `Activator`. See [activator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598088/purpose-of-activator-createinstance-with-example)

Comment: As you can see in my last comment I'm not using no args constructor, but I edited that my own. That still throws the exception...