# .NET interoperability

Tags: c#, interop

My C++ code is using CreateInstance(CLSID_CxSsampleObject). I'm rewriting my C++ component in C#. I need to use some legacy COM objects in my C# code. What is the equivalent of CreateInstance in C#. Also, what's the equivalent of QueryInterface in C#. Appreciate your help if you can point me to any articles on .NET interoperability.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598088/purpose-of-activator-createinstance-with-example

Comment: [Calling COM Components from .NET Clients](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973800.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: [Best way to access COM objects from C#](//stackoverflow.com/q/635839)